# Why does Data have to ask the computer for directions?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

In "Brothers," Data's father activates a sort of homing signal in the android's positronic net, in order that the two are reunited.

While on the bridge, and before creating a security code, Data asks the computer for the quickest route to the transporter room, since he is unable to transport from his current location.

Why does Data have to do this? As an android, I cannot believe he doesn't have the entire ship memorized, deck by deck. I guess, perhaps, that Soong's tinkering affected his ability to remember certain things, but that doesn't sound convincing.

Comment: Could just be a case of "As you know" (http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AsYouKnow). WARNING!! TVtropes-Link! Hours lost are not reimbursable!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unless I'm much mistaken, he's not asking the computer to show him the route (which, as you say he already knows), he's asking the computer to display the route **so that the computer can be told which forcefields to disable.**

He also needs to see where people are located, so that he can open and close forcefields without encountering the security teams.

> **DATA :** Show me the shortest route to Transporter Room One.
>
> The computer beeps and a route map appears in front of Data.
>
> **DATA :** Computer, prepare to activate a cascade force field sequence in
>   the following progression.